# What will happen in PostgreSQL if a cascading delete is attempted on the parent of a locked row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, transaction-isolation

I have a table `foo_bar` and another table `spam_eggs` with a `fb` foreign key pointing to `foo_bar`. `spam_eggs` rows are cascade deleted when their related `spam_eggs.fb` are deleted.

I'm working with PostgreSQL.

In a transaction I have used `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` to lock a `spam_eggs` row. In the duration of this transaction, another transaction has attempted to `DELETE FROM...` the related `foo_bar` of my locked row. Will this trigger an error, or will my locked row cause the query to block until the end of my original update transaction?

Comment: Short version: It'll block. Long version: When it unblocks, what happens depends on what the isolation level of the two transactions is, what else the 1st transaction did, and whether the 1st transaction rolled back or committed. See answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try it and see. Open `psql` and do some setup:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_bar(id integer primary key);
CREATE TABLE spam_eggs(
     foo_bar_id integer not null references foo_bar(id) on delete cascade
);
INSERT INTO foo_bar (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO spam_eggs(foo_bar_id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

then open another psql connection. `BEGIN` a transaction in both of them.

1. In the first (old) session, run `SELECT 1 FROM spam_eggs WHERE foo_bar_id = 4 FOR UPDATE;`
2. In the second (new) session, run `DELETE FROM foo_bar WHERE id = 4;`

You will see that the second statement blocks on the first. That's because the `DELETE` on `foo_bar` cascades to `spam_eggs` and attempts to lock the row with the foreign key reference so it can delete it. That lock blocks on the lock held by the `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`.

In general, try to test in all these circumstances:

- tx's are `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` and first issues a `ROLLBACK`
- tx's are `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` and first issues a `COMMIT`
- tx's are `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and first issues a `ROLLBACK`
- tx's are `BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and first issues a `COMMIT`

to make sure you know what to expect. It's also good for your learning if you *reason through what you expect to happen before testing it*.

In this case the `READ COMMITTED` and `SERIALIZABLE` isolation levels will behave the same. If you actually do an `UPDATE` after your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and then `COMMIT` then they'll behave differently, though; the `READ COMMITTED` version will `DELETE` successfully, while the `SERIALIZABLE` version will fail with:

```
regress=# BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
regress=# DELETE FROM foo_bar WHERE id = 4;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update                                                                                                                                                        
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "public"."spam_eggs" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "foo_bar_id""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Craig. I appreciate all the details.